# ViewPager Tab Navigation Fragment ActionBar Menu Issue

Tags: android, tabs, navigation, android-actionbar, fragment

I'm facing an issue with my app.

I set up a `ViewPager` with three actionbar tabs.
When the App is openend, the next tab is preloaded (or something)

Example: I swipe from tab A to tab B. When tab B is displayed, tab C is created in the background.

Tab C itself has a special ActionBar Menu item, which should be displayed only in tab 3. Because it gets preloaded, this symbol is displayed in both tab B and tab C.

If I call `setHasOptionsMenu(false)` in tab B, tab C overwrites it with its `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` (I still want to display the special item)

I googled and stackoverflowed a few hours to find a workaround, but unfortunately, I got no results.

Is there any way to fix this and can somebody explain this behavior to me?

**EDIT: Some Code.**

*MainActivity*

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_pager);

    mPagerAdapter =new MyPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            //invalidateOptionsMenu();
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });


    actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    tabListener = new FilmKisteTabListener();
    for (int tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(tabListener));
    }   
}

protected class FilmKisteTabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // Nothing

    }
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }
}


/*@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.kiste_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {



    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "YOU SHALL NOT PASS!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}*/

@Override
public void libraryRefresh() {      
    /**
     * Tell adapter to update the views
     * content has changed
     */
    mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Aktualisiert", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}


@Override
public void onFilmAdded() {
    /**
     * Tell adapter to update the views
     * content has changed
     */
    mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Arbeit ist vollbracht", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


@Override
public void onFilmDeleted(String name) {
    mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    Toast.makeText(this, name + " wurde verbannt.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
@Override
public void onReturn() {
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.
            LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
}
```

*Fragment 1: LibraryFragment (Which is loaded by default)*

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_bibliothek, container, false);
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    initialize();
}

public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    //View init here!
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
}


private void initialize() {

    db = new DatabaseHelper(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    valueList = new ArrayList<Film>();
    resList = new ArrayList<String>();

    valueList = db.getAllFilms();


    for(int i = 0; i < valueList.size(); i++) {
        resList.add(valueList.get(i).getName());
    }

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, resList);

    ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getActivity())
    .setTitle("Löschen?")
    .setMessage("Der Film sollte nur gelöscht werden, wenn es keinen weiteren Teil gibt.")
    .setPositiveButton("Ja", this)
    .setNegativeButton("Nein", null);

}

public interface LibraryRefreshCallback {
    public void libraryRefresh();
}

private void refresh()  {
    //TODO UPDATE
    callback.libraryRefresh();

   // Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), "Aktualisiert", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        // Activities containing this fragment must implement its callbacks
        try{
            callback = (LibraryRefreshCallback) activity;
        }catch(ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement LibraryRefreshCallback");
        }

}

//popup onClick
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
    //Created in @see onItemClick
    db.deleteFilm(film);

    refresh();

}

@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    String selectedFromList = (String) (arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2));

    //System.out.println(selectedFromList);
    film = new Film();
    film.setName(selectedFromList);
    System.out.println("DEL: "+film.getName());

    //Show popup
    ad.show();
    return true;

}
```

*Fragment 2: add (which displays optionmenuitems from fragment 3 when called)*

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_add_film, container, false);
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
    setHasOptionsMenu(false);


    initialize();
}

public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    //View init here!

    btnSpeichern = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_add_film_speichern);
    btnSpeichern.setOnClickListener(this);

    editFilmName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_add_film_name);

}



private void initialize() {
    db = new DatabaseHelper(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getActivity())
    .setTitle("Bestätigung")
    .setMessage("Wirklick speichern?")
    .setNegativeButton("Nein", null)
    .setPositiveButton("Ja", this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    hideSoftKeyboard();
    ad.show();
}

private void hideSoftKeyboard() {
    imm = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(
              Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editFilmName.getWindowToken(), 0);
}

@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
    db.addFilm(editFilmName.getText().toString());

    //Film added; return to library.

    callback.onFilmAdded();

}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(
      Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.removeItem(R.menu.kiste_random_film);
   //inflater.inflate(R.menu.kiste_main, menu);


    /*
     * ActionBar will display the TrashBin because it
     * prepares the next fragment (with its actionbar items)
     * 
     * TODO
     * find a way to hide
     */
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

public interface FilmAddedListener {
    public void onFilmAdded();
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        // Activities containing this fragment must implement its callbacks
        try{
            callback = (FilmAddedListener) activity;
        }catch(ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement FilmAddedListener");
        }

}

public void setUserVisibibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

    if(this.isVisible()) {
        if(!isVisibleToUser) {
            hideSoftKeyboard();
        }
    }
}
```

*Fragment 3: Which has an OptionMenu*

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_zufalls_film, container, false);
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    initialize();
}

public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    //View init here!
    viewFilm = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.zufallsfilm_zufallsfilm);

    viewFilm.setText(film.getName().toString());

}

private void initialize() {

    db = new DatabaseHelper(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    poolIDs = db.getAvailableFilmIDs();

    r = new Random();

    Log.i("POOL_SIZE",""+poolIDs.size());

    randNum = r.nextInt(poolIDs.size());

    Log.i("RANDOM_GEN",""+randNum);
    film = db.getFilm(poolIDs.get(randNum));


    ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getActivity())
    .setTitle("Löschen?")
    .setMessage("Der Film sollte nur gelöscht werden, wenn es keinen weiteren Teil gibt.")
    .setNegativeButton("Nein", new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            callback.onReturn();
        }
    })
    .setPositiveButton("Ja", this);

    ai = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getActivity())
    .setTitle("Status")
    .setNeutralButton("OK", null);

}


private void handleBack() {
    ad.show();
}

@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
    db.deleteFilm(film); //Can return boolean @see del
    callback.onFilmDeleted(film.getName());
}

@Override
public void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    getView().requestFocus();
    getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){

                handleBack();

                return true;

            }

            return false;
        }
    });

  //To enable ActionBarItems
    if(isVisible()) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(
      Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    if(isVisible()) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.kiste_random_film, menu);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    //isVisible() doesn't work the way I expected it.
 if(isVisible()) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_delete:
                handleBack();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


public interface FilmDeletedListener {
    void onFilmDeleted(String name);
    void onReturn();
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        // Activities containing this fragment must implement its callbacks
        try{
            callback = (FilmDeletedListener) activity;
        }catch(ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement FilmDeletedListener");
        }

}
```

*getItem(..) method from my MyPagerAdapter (extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter)*

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {
    Log.d("MPA","SWITCHED TO POS "+ index);

    switch(index) {
    case 0:
        Log.d("MPA","RETURN LIB");
        return new LibraryFragment();
    case 1: 
        Log.d("MPA","RETURN NEW");
        return new SomethingNewFragment();
    case 2: 
        Log.d("MPA","RETURN RAN");
        return new ForGreatEntertainmentFragment();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Post your code - I guess you might be using some static variable that may override